# How to fix NativeModule.RNLocalize is null?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-localize

I am using `react-native-localization` library is my RN project.

My RN version is `0.59.4`

I already get the project to work on android as expected, but the problem is with the `IOS` build.

I `npm` installed both `react-native-localization` and `react-native-localize` and linked them as described in their github manual using pod.

I did everything I could from linking to clean and building the project multiple times.

But I'm getting this error when running `react-native-localize NativeModule.RNLocalize is null. To fix this issue try these steps` and I did what the console told me but IN VAIN.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm looking for the same, just found some people asking the same, dealing with expo (not my case) but nothing works. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045191/how-to-resolve-a-nativemodule-rnlocalize-is-null-error-in-test

Answer (score 2):

Create a mock file like this (in the root directory):

```
__mocks__/react-native-localize.js
```

Check that `__mock__` has two underscores.

This is an example of the file:

```
const getLocales = () => [
  // you can choose / add the locales you want
  { countryCode: "US", languageTag: "en-US", languageCode: "en", isRTL: false },
  { countryCode: "FR", languageTag: "fr-FR", languageCode: "fr", isRTL: false },
];

// use a provided translation, or return undefined to test your fallback
const findBestAvailableLanguage = () => ({
  languageTag: "en-US",
  isRTL: false,
});

const getNumberFormatSettings = () => ({
  decimalSeparator: ".",
  groupingSeparator: ",",
});

const getCalendar = () => "gregorian"; // or "japanese", "buddhist"
const getCountry = () => "US"; // the country code you want
const getCurrencies = () => ["USD", "EUR"]; // can be empty array
const getTemperatureUnit = () => "celsius"; // or "fahrenheit"
const getTimeZone = () => "Europe/Paris"; // the timezone you want
const uses24HourClock = () => true;
const usesMetricSystem = () => true;

const addEventListener = jest.fn();
const removeEventListener = jest.fn();

export {
  findBestAvailableLanguage,
  getLocales,
  getNumberFormatSettings,
  getCalendar,
  getCountry,
  getCurrencies,
  getTemperatureUnit,
  getTimeZone,
  uses24HourClock,
  usesMetricSystem,
  addEventListener,
  removeEventListener,
};
```

You don't have to import the `node_module` of `react-native-localization` because each file under `__mocks__` will be automatically mocked.

Try to run the test again and check if the error persist.

Edit: in my case, the only function that I needed from `react-native-localize` was `uses24HourClock()` so my mock file was very short:

```
const uses24HourClock = () => false;

export { uses24HourClock };
```

That was all for me.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I already moved to `I18n` but I will try this later on.