# Failed to instal the app react native android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, build, peer-dependencies

it turns out that I recently updated react native from version 0.59 to 0.66 and now that I want to run it it doesn't work. I am really desperate, I have been trying to solve for a month, please help, please

This is the message I get on the console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3SN7.png)

Mi packege json:

https://github.com/IzliaB/Librerias

Y el error que recibo en Android:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpdOF.png)

I am already really frustrated, I have to present this project next week and I have not been able to move forward and it is incredible that there is no clear documentation on these types of problems. I have tried over and over again deleting the node_module folder, searching and installing the dependencies manually, probe ./gradle clean, probe deleting the android folder, I tested so many things in this month. I'm tired, please help me

the project is in yarn

Comment: did you try create fresh project with 'those problems' package ?

Comment: not really, how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is giving an error in the `react-native-file-opener` and `react-native-fetch-blob` packages. try uninstall those packages and re-install them. and in your package.json I can't find `react-native-fetch-blob` may be it's not installed properly reinstall these packages and try

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me, I tried your recommendation, but after several attempts and reboots I receive the following error:
MainApplication.java:8: error: package io.github.elyx0.reactnativedocumentpicker does not exist
import io.github.elyx0.reactnativedocumentpicker.DocumentPickerPackage;                     
C:\Users\citDe\Documents\\android\app\src\main\java\com\doktoapp\MainApplication.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
import io.sentry.RNSentryPackage;
        ^  symbol:   class RNSentryPackage
  location: package io.sentry

Comment: Add the full error to the repository to show you better in img
https://github.com/IzliaB/Librerias

Comment: errors in `react-native-file-opener` and `react-native-fetch-blob` packages have been solved now and it's showing an error in the file picker. so try what you have done with those like reinstall file picker or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045191/how-to-resolve-a-nativemodule-rnlocalize-is-null-error-in-test)